# Find all files by name recursively, decrypt and rename them using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a script to find all of the files with `.production` in names, decrypt those files and save copies of them without `.production`.

Example files:

```
./functions/key.production.json
./src/config.production.js
```

Here is my code:

```
decrypt() {
  echo $1

  for file in $(find . -name "*.$1.*")
  do
      echo "some $file"
      openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass pass:asdffdsa -in $file -out $(sed -e "p;s/.$1//")
  done
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error? What is the problem?

Comment: @franzisk no errors, no effect. Just echoing the first file name and hangs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(sed -e "p;s/.$1//")` is the part that hangs. You can check that out by adding `set -x` and executing your script. This is because `sed` expectes an input file/stream, and there is none given to it.

You could rather use bash substring replacement `"${file//.$1}"`

> ${string//$substring_to_remove/}

All occurrences of the content after `//` is replaced in the main string, with the content after the last `/`

So, the working function would be

```
decrypt() {
  echo $1

  for file in $(find . -name "*.$1.*")
  do
      echo "some $file"
      openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass pass:asdffdsa -in $file -out "${file//.$1}"
  done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the subshell **$(find . -name "*.$1.*")** by using a while loop.

```
decrypt() {
  echo "$1"
  local file
  while read -r file; do
    echo "some $file"
    PROCESS-YOUR-FILE-AND-DO-YOUR-STUFF_HERE
  done < <(find . -name "*.$1.*")
}
```

see

Comment: why do I need to avoid it?

Comment: If  there are spaces or newlines in some of the file/path names that find output will have some errors while processing it. Well it may or may not happen now but it will.